# Implementing XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS attribute on STUN server

Tags: node.js, ip-address, p2p, xor, stun

From [RFC 5389 Section 15.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-15.2):

> If the IP
> address family is IPv4, X-Address is computed by taking the mapped IP
> address in host byte order, XOR'ing it with the magic cookie, and
> converting the result to network byte order.  If the IP address
> family is IPv6, X-Address is computed by taking the mapped IP address
> in host byte order, XOR'ing it with the concatenation of the magic
> cookie and the 96-bit transaction ID, and converting the result to
> network byte order.

I'm writing a STUN server in Node.JS and I'm trying to understand how one would go about XOR-ing a 128-bit value. I feel as though it would involve using one of these functions from the [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuintle_offset_bytelength_noassert) module, though it says it only supports up to 48 bits. Any advice on how to implement a 128-bit XOR operator for an IPv6 address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my XOR operator from my CryptoPals code:

```
var xor = function (b0, b1) {
  if (Buffer.isBuffer(b0)) {
    b0 = new Buffer(b0);
  }
  if (Buffer.isBuffer(b1)) {
    b1 = new Buffer(b1);
  }

  if (b0.length !== b1.length) {
    console.log(b0.length, b1.length);
    throw new Error('Tried to xor two buffers of differing length');
  }

  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < b0.length; i++) {
    arr.push(b0[i] ^ b1[i]);
  }

  return new Buffer(arr);
};
```

Comment: Just one question about my particular use-case. Is an IPv6 guaranteed to be 16 bytes, or is it possible that it will be less bytes? If it can be less, how do I pad the value?

Comment: Wait nevermind, I think IPv6 is guaranteed to be 16 bytes when formatted properly.